# Can I send the computed result in the background task in Django to the frontend (Angular)?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, python-multiprocessing

In the Django view, I have used the multiprocessing module of python and have successfully made parallel requests to Julia's server using the map function of the multiprocessing module. The result is automatically given as a list to the view and I return the results list to Frontend using HTTP response.

However, Julia takes nearly 10 minutes to compute 1 task and even after parallel processing it consumes a lot of time and the frontend has to wait way too long for the final response to come through.

So for each call to Julia, I need to send the computed result back to the frontend so it can start working on this data.

I do not want to use Celery.
Any ideas on how to send HTTP requests to the frontend from the subprocesses themselves?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. One of the possible way to do that is using Message Broker through AMQP (Advanced Message Queuing Protocol) like Rabbitmq.

You can make a publisher and subscriber of the computing task, so there is no need for http to wait the task complete before it's return http response.

Hope you can [learn it more here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) Or any other Message Broker systems.

Comment: @yukta Is there any update from you?